# CakePHP 2.1 display records by custom order

Tags: database, customization, cakephp-2.1

I created two tables 'college' and'users' and the structure is as follows.

```
college('id', 'name').
users('id', 'name', 'dob').
```

While adding college, I have to select users in select box. So I have to give custom order for user-name while adding like (1, 2, 3, etc), So easily I can display it in order when displaying college. Even I thought that creating another table for custom-order for each user. But its very lengthy process for each college in my perception.

If my logic is good, then suggest me how to do that?. If any other solutions you have plase suggest me. The work will be more appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

From what I understand, you are looking for ways to link users to a college. Using a HABTM table, you have the flexibility of assigning users to a college without messing with any of the college / user data directly. You are merely linking the two records together. Not to mention, you can link multiple users to multiple colleges and viceversa.

To create a HABTM table, it will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE colleges_users (
  id char(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  college_id char(36) NOT NULL, 
  user_id char(36) NOT NULL
);
```

Then simply add the relationships inside both models.